# Precise statement of the syntactic category of a logic/type theory, in maximum generality?

Tags: category-theory, type-theory, formal-systems, categorical-logic

I've been trying to understand the notion of syntactic category for a type theory/logic. [This entry in the ncatlab](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/syntactic+category) is the closest I've found to a clear explanation.
It seems like a fairly good article, but it is not yet entirely clear to me, as it doesn't seem fully precise (whereas others resources seem more formal but rely on a lot of extra technical baggage).

**I'd like a precise statement of (1) what exactly do we need to assume from a "type theory" in order to define its syntactic category, and (2) how exactly is the category constructed from the formal system, what are the morphisms precisely.**

To illustrate why the ncatlab article doesnt clarify this for me fully:

- Presumably this construction works for a very large class of formal deduction systems, rather than specifically for "type theories". This makes the adjunction between theories and categories somewhat ambiguous to me. What exactly do we include in the category of "theories" in this context?
- Is a morphism an arbitrary sequence of typing judgments $\Delta \vdash t:T$, or is it a *derivation* of such a statement in the given type theory's formal deduction system? The article seems to say both at different points.
- There is a comment in the article itself stating that it is incomplete.

Comment: Pitts's [Categorical logic](https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~amp12/papers/catl/catl.pdf) is a good starting point for understanding these topics.

Comment: @varkor, I have started reading it, and it is good. However the term "syntactic category" does not appear in the text.

Comment: The construction there is called the "classifying category", which is synonymous with "syntactic category".

Comment: I think the current status of the problem is that everyone intuitively knows it, but nobody bothered to state a precise general version of it :(

Comment: Btw the exact term [syntactic category](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_category) is also used in linguistics.

Comment: I have an idea about the free monad over an endospan. More generally a logical theory is a well-founded tree of antecedents and consequents so some sort of W-type ought to be the right way of thinking of things. I think the most general approach ought to be some sort of polynomial endofunctor in Cat. I think I also want to look at displayed categories. But this sort of higher categorical stuff is far too hairy and advanced for me.

Comment: @MolossusSpondee, I mostly don't understand the terms you're using :).

Comment: A free monad on an endospan sounds fancy but boils down to just iterating a template. In Coq something like `Inductive free {R C} (p: R -> C * C) : C -> C -> Type := | id A: free p A A | roll {A} r: free p A (fst (p r)) -> free p A (snd (p r)).` A W-type is just fancy jargon for an inductive data type. A polynomial endofunctor in Cat "ought" to be the proper way of algebraically building up a category out of bits and pieces like an inductive type but it's too hairy for me